# std::shared_ptr crash with MSVC on different computer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, redistributable

Compiling and running the following simple program works fine on my developer machine (Visual Studio 2015, 64-bit).

Running the same code on a different machine crashes with the windows error dialog, even though the x64-redistributables are installed (msvcp140.dll):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::shared_ptr<int> test; // comment out to run on both machines

  std::cout << "Done: " << std::endl;
}
```

Removing the line with the shared pointer makes it work.

**Any idea what the problem could be here, or how to debug?**

Comment: Seems like problem with the msvcp140.dll  Copy the working dll from the other system in your application folder and test again.

Comment: collect minidump from the crashing machine and investigate. what's the error? what config? (I think in `release` this line shouldn't make any difference as would be completely optimised out). and just in case, double check you really tried *this* code on both machines

Comment: What error message?

Comment: Use the MSVC remote debugger to attach to the crashing app on the different machine

Comment: @Andy T: Its release configuration, and I think its not optimized out since the compiler has to run the constructor and destructor of the shared_ptr. I copied the executable, so I'm sure its the exact same code.

Comment: @SimonKraemer: The error message is the genereric message seen here (with my program name instead of Google Chrome): https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5EGYpW0PWvY/hqdefault.jpg

Comment: @RichardCritten: The other machine is a customer laptop, where I cannot install stuff, unfortunately.

Comment: @seccpur: msvcp140.dll has a lot of dependencies I think, like vcruntime140.dll and so on. Should I copy all of these as well? Which ones do I need? What do I doo if it also crashes on my machine then?

Comment: Don't copy it, install it properly or if you cannot do this - use static linking with c-runtime so your app will have it embedded into the executable

Comment: @JanRuegg: Not all, just msvcp140.dll and msvcp140p.dll perhaps , copy to app folder ( not in system folder) just to test the dll.

Comment: @AndyT: I did install it with the installer, which is what isn't working. Linking statically is hard since I have a lot of dependencies in the "real" project. I could try just for testing, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the solution now... (see answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, in case this is useful for anyone:

In the windows event viewer, I discovered the reason for the crash: The exception was `0xc000001d` or `illegal instruction`. Appareantly my code was compiled using the `/arch:AVX` compile flag, resulting in the following code for the snippet above:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
00007FF749A816B0  sub         rsp,48h  
00007FF749A816B4  mov         qword ptr [rsp+20h],0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEh  
00007FF749A816BD  vpxor       xmm0,xmm0,xmm0  
00007FF749A816C1  vmovdqu     xmmword ptr [test],xmm0  
  std::shared_ptr<int> test; // comment out to run on both machines

  std::cout << "Done: " << std::endl;
00007FF749A816C7  lea         rdx,[string "Done: " (07FF749A86C70h)]  
00007FF749A816CE  mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cout (07FF749A8A0D8h)]  
00007FF749A816D5  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (07FF749A8107Dh)  
  ...
```

As you can see, because of the `/arch:AVX` the `vpxor` and `vmovdqu` instructions were generated, which do not run on processors that are too old (like the one I tested with).

**The solution is to have separate versions of the executable (or separate paths through the program) with and without AVX instructions to support older processors.**